# How to align text vertically within bootstrap progress bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I modified the height of the bootstrap progress bar as you can see in the following link:
http://jsfiddle.net/8Xf2j/31/

What I'm trying to make is that the text is centered vertically. I tried to add the property:

```
vertical-align:middle
```

But it does not works... I also want to increase the font size of the text containing the progress bar adding:

```
font-size:30px;
```

As you'll see in de fiddle it doesn't works too.
Any idea or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to achieve vertical alignment of a single line of text is to make the `line-height` match the desired height.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/VQS2k/

```
.progress {
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.bar {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

**Plain version (no Bootstrap):** http://jsfiddle.net/VQS2k/1/

Comment: Ok, really thanks!! But what about the _font-size_? does not work on the fiddle you entered.

Comment: Font-size is being overridden by the bootstrap styles. I just put together a plain version so you can see.

Comment: Just be aware that if you use this technique, it only works if your text does not wrap.

Comment: @cimmanon - yes, I find it's mainly useful for developer-defined text (such as found on buttons) versus user input.